# How to free an array of structure and objects in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, struct, delete-operator

The structure of the program is as such, there is a header file manager.h in which C++ class is defined with data members and member functions. Then in a manager.C file the member functions are implemented.

I've defined 3 structs in the .c file.

```
#define HTSIZE 7

struct Node
{
int value;
int page;   
struct Node *next; 
};

struct Node *hashtable[HTSIZE];


struct lruNode{
int value;
struct lruNode *next;
struct lruNode* head;
struct lruNode* tail;

};

struct lruNode* lruhashtable[HTSIZE];
struct lruNode* lruTrackHead;
struct lruNode* lruTrackTail;


struct mruNode{
int value;
struct mruNode *next;    
 };

 struct mruNode* mruTrackHead=NULL;
 struct mruNode* mruhashtable[HTSIZE];
```

The data members of class are as follows:
Class Name:Page

Class Name:Frame

Class Name:Manager

All the structs are declared in manager.C

manager.h has the following data members.

```
Page* pagePool;
Frame* framePool;
```

In manager.C I'm defining them as

```
pagePool=new Page[n];
framePool=new Frame[n];
```

In the destructor for manager.C

I'm doing

```
delete[] pagePool;
delete[] framePool;
*hashtable=NULL;
*lruhashtable=NULL;
*mruhashtable=NULL;
```

The structs here are global and not part of the class as such. This is part of my homework. The problem is in my test-cases I'm carry forwarding the previous test case values.

I did an edit to set the pointers the way they are. Now the first value in the array for all array of pointers to struct is null.

Still the array of pointers to objects are not freed up. Can someone comment on that?

**Edit**

On iterating through a loop, the pointers are freed.

But still the array of pointers to objects are not?

Comment: How about using `std::vector`, which will do the dirty job for you.

Comment: What is Page ans Frame? Why are you freeing what was not allocated?

Comment: Why use free for hashtables ? Are you using malloc for them ?

Comment: Not using malloc for hashtables. Page and Frame are two classes.

Comment: Unrelated, but I wouldn't recommend using `.C` for C++ files. Use `.cpp`. It's more obvious, *much* more common, will be recognised by more tools, and works on Windows.

Comment: Kinda hard to give the right advice here.  We cannot see how these structures are used.  For instance, it looks to me like the nodes form a list, and are indexed by a hash table.  In that case, iterating through the list and deleting each node is independent from deleting the hash table.  But I wonder about `Page` and `Frame` in a file called `manager`.  Are these memory-management objects?

Comment: @paddy Yes Page and Manager are memory managment objects. The hashtable is an array of linked. Same for lru and mru.

Comment: Well, this stuff is generally simple.  The memory manager should probably delete all memory that it allocated.  And you should probably delete all memory that *you* allocated.  Making us guess how all this stuff fits together is counter-productive.  If you have values being carried forward then you are leaving something uninitialised or you are not cleaning up properly.  Memory leaks are a side-issue.

Comment: @Paddy Is delete[] pagePool correct for an array of pointers to a object

Comment: Yes.  And you might want to clear your entire hash table instead of just the first element, unless that's enough to describe the table as being empty.

Comment: I did clear the entire hashtable but the array of pointers to the classes are not getting freed?

Comment: @Timmmm Please note that [the homework tag is deprecated and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call

free(hashtable);

you dealocate memory alocated for an array of

```
int value;
int page;   
struct Node *
```

but the memory alocated for structure that is pointed by Node is note dealocated.

The main idea is to dealocate from the "deepest pointed" structure to top. So try to do a bottom up dealocation ,in reverse order that it was alocated.

Comment: your architecture is not clear in the question : if node is a part of a list, you can delete a node from the list and link node-1 to node+1 or delete the entire list.

Comment: an exemple will be the following struct Node
{
int value;
int page;   
struct Node *next; 
};


struct Node *hashtable[HTSIZE];

alocation
hashtable =  new Node [HTSIZE]
for (int i = 0 ; i < HTSIZE ; ++i)
{
   hashtable->Node   = new Node();
}



dealocation

for (int i = 0 ; i < HTSIZE ; ++i)
{
   delete hashtable->Node;
}

delete [hashtable] ;

Comment: @AdrianHerea : you have to begin dealocation with the end,... `for (int i = HTSIZE - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) { delete hashtable->Node; } delete hashtable;`, else you will lose the reference to the third node and the following ones.

Comment: in real situation you need to do it in a recursive mode or an itaration method with the same effect. But in my exemple, which is only an exemple, node aren't linked. I just wanted to explain what I want to say with bottom up dealocation.